# fill missing indices in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

x = pd.Series([1, 2, 4], [datetime(2013,11,1), datetime(2013,11, 2), datetime(2013, 11, 4)])
```

The missing index at November 3rd corresponds to a zero value, and I want it to look like this:

```
y = pd.Series([1,2,0,4], pd.date_range('2013-11-01', periods = 4))
```

What's the best way to convert x to y?  I've tried

```
y = pd.Series(x, pd.date_range('2013-11-1', periods = 4)).fillna(0)
```

This throws an index error sometimes which I can't interpret (Index length did not match values, even though index and data have the same length.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.resample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html) for this:

```
>>> x.resample('D').fillna(0)
2013-11-01    1
2013-11-02    2
2013-11-03    0
2013-11-04    4
```

There's `fill_method` parameter in the `resample()` function, but I don't know if it's possible to use it to replace `NaN` during resampling. But looks like you can use `how` method to take care of it, like:

```
>>> x.resample('D', how=lambda x: x.mean() if len(x) > 0 else 0)
2013-11-01    1
2013-11-02    2
2013-11-03    0
2013-11-04    4
```

Don't know which method is preferred one. Please also take a look at @AndyHayden's answer - probably `reindex()` with `fill_value=0` would be most efficien way to do this, but you have to make your own tests.

Comment: +1 you beat me answer this by 11 seconds, I had to add another option, I would choose this though.

Comment: @AndyHayden thanks, I was actually hoping that there's `fill_method` for replacing `NaN`s

Comment: @RomanPekar there is with reindex, so that will probably be the most efficient... (I expect fillna is faster than that lambda!)

Answer (score 9):

I think I would use a [resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html) (note if there are dupes it takes the mean by default):

```
In [11]: x.resample('D')  # you could use how='first'
Out[11]: 
2013-11-01     1
2013-11-02     2
2013-11-03   NaN
2013-11-04     4
Freq: D, dtype: float64

In [12]: x.resample('D').fillna(0)
Out[12]: 
2013-11-01    1
2013-11-02    2
2013-11-03    0
2013-11-04    4
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

If you prefered dupes to raise, then use [reindex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
In [13]: x.reindex(pd.date_range('2013-11-1', periods=4), fill_value=0)
Out[13]: 
2013-11-01   1
2013-11-02   2
2013-11-03   0
2013-11-04   4
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Comment: +1 for ye fo reindex. It's hard to choose when there're so many ways to do this simple task :)

Comment: reindex is useful when not working with dates